# What crops do the peasants in "The Naked Island" grow?

Tags: naked-island

In [The Naked Island](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0056049/) from [Kaneto Shindô](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0793881/) we see a pair of peasants growing crops on an island.

Some of their crops seem to be some kind of wheat. But they seem to grow something else, too.

What do they grow on the naked island?

[You can watch the film on Youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OjVtXe2pLaU)

Wheat?
[image]

A small bushy plant(to her left, not the big ones to the right):
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Toronto J-Film Pow-Wow](http://jfilmpowwow.blogspot.com/2008/07/review-naked-island-kaneto-shindo-1960.html):

> They grow a meager crop of potatoes and wheat to eat and to sell

They include a screenshot of an islander tending to grown wheat:

[image: wheat]

And here's a photo of potato plants with pointed leaves:

[image: potatoes]

(Photo from Wikipedia by [Fir0002/Flagstaffotos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Potato_plants.jpg))